# Scalafx and CSS Stylesheets

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am creating a scalafx application and I cannot get it to communicate with an external stylesheet. I get a NullPointerException if I use

getClass.getResource

and if I do

stylesheets = "styles.css"

I get a message from sbt saying it cannot find my stylesheet. I have scoured the internet and tried to mimic what other projects have done but still have this same problem. Here is a portion of my code where I add the stylesheet. Both files are in the same directory.

```
object Main extends JFXApp with toolbarComponent with menubarComponent {
  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene(880, 520) {
      stylesheets = List(getClass.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm)
...
}
```

My directory structure goes like this:

[Directory File] ->

src ->

main ->

scala, resources ->

Both files are in 'scala' directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"styles.css" needs to be in the `resources` under sub-directory corresponding to package where `Main` class is.

Comment: Thank you very much! Big help.